# Linking of asp dot net using linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, hyperlink

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class First : System.Web.UI.Page
{ MyDataClassesDataContext mdc;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mdc = new MyDataClassesDataContext();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
}

private void LoadData()
{
    mdc = new MyDataClassesDataContext();
    var empls = from em in mdc.Emps select em;

    GVEmp.DataSource = empls;
    GVEmp.DataBind();

    var ddlempls = from em in mdc.Emps
            select new
            {
                em.EmpID,
                em.Ename
            };

    DDLEmp.DataSource = ddlempls;
    DDLEmp.DataTextField = "Ename";
    DDLEmp.DataValueField = "EmpID";
    DDLEmp.DataBind();
    DDLEmp.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
}
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Emp em = new Emp();
    em.Ename = TxtName.Text;
    em.Sal = Int32.Parse(TxtSal.Text);

    mdc.Emps.InsertOnSubmit(em);
    mdc.SubmitChanges();
    LoadData();
    LabDisp.Text = "Record Added";
}
protected void DDLEmp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ Emp empl = mdc.Emps.Single(em => em.EmpID ==Int32.Parse(DDLEmp.SelectedItem.Value));

    if (empl != null)
    {
        TxtName0.Text = empl.Ename;
        TxtSal0.Text = empl.Sal.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        LabDisp.Text = "Data not found";
    }
}
protected void LBUpd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Emp empl = mdc.Emps.Single(em => em.EmpID ==Int32.Parse(DDLEmp.SelectedItem.Value));

    if (empl != null)
    {
        empl.Ename = TxtName0.Text;
        empl.Sal=Int32.Parse(TxtSal0.Text);
        mdc.SubmitChanges();
        LoadData();
        LabDisp.Text = "record updated";
    }
    else
    {
        LabDisp.Text = "Data not found";
    }
}
protected void LBDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Emp empl = mdc.Emps.Single(em => em.EmpID == Int32.Parse(DDLEmp.SelectedItem.Value));

    if (empl != null)
    {
        mdc.Emps.DeleteOnSubmit(empl);
        mdc.SubmitChanges();
        LoadData();
        LabDisp.Text = "record deleted";
    }
    else
    {
        LabDisp.Text = "Data not found";
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone please help and explain about this code...one of my friend send this and 
  a config file to me to link an asp page with database..there are certain things like `MyDataClassesDataContext,GVEmp.DataSource` which are very new to me and i don't understand any of those

Comment: I'm sorry, but explaining huge blocks of code is not the purpose of this site. If learning about C# and Linq interests you, there are numerous blogs and books and other resources you should try. Ask Stack Overflow when you have a *very specific* and well researched question about a coding problem, and we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code is using EntityFrameWork or Linq2SQL or so... These links may be helpful

- [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)
- [The ADO.NET Entity Framework Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Linq to SQL - Linq2SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)

Read up on those tools